# Python: Requirements file for Conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was given a requirements file that looks like this:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
arrow-cpp                 0.13.0           py37h29c365f_3    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                py37_1003    conda-forge
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  

etc...
```

I went ahead and changed it to

```
#Name Version Build Channel
appnope=0.1.0=py37_0
arrow-cpp=0.13.0=py37h29c365f_3=conda-forge
asn1crypto=0.24.0=py37_1003=conda-forge
astroid=2.2.5=py37_0
atomicwrites=1.3.0=pypi_0=pypi
attrs=19.1.0=pypi_0=pypi
backcall=0.1.0=py37_0
blas=1.0=mkl

etc...
```

I am a bit new to virtual environements, so when I go to create it, I'm getting this error

```
conda create --name solver --file spec.txt

CondaValueError: could not parse 'asn1crypto=0.24.0=py37_1003=conda-forge' in: file.txt
```

So I went ahead and removed the build and channel field from each of them.

But now I'm getting

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - teradatasqlalchemy==16.20.0.7
  - ortools==7.1.6720
  - grpcio==1.24.3
  - pyathenajdbc==2.0.4
  - gcc==4.8.5
  - docplex==2.9.133
  - idna==2.8000
  - redis==3.3.5
  - docloud==1.0.257
  - teradatasql==16.20.0.48
  - pyorc==0.3.0
  - cplex==12.9.0.0
  - docutils==0.14001
  - ray==0.7.1

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pypi/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pypi/noarch
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually and https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file

Comment: _I was given a requirements file that looks like this:_ That's an impractical format, you should ask for a proper environment.yml file if at all possible. _I went ahead and changed it to_ What format is that in?

Comment: In case you can't get an original `environment.yml` for the env, here's [an AWK script](https://gist.github.com/mfansler/5a1a703d1ac6bb2139547003248c3827) that will convert from the `conda list` output, e.g., `conda list | awk -f list_to_yaml.awk > environment.yml`